# Hide Repeater Element with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to hide the repeater element that already added in table but now I faced some problem which is even I done for the comparison condition the repeater will also show out the overall content based on the table. Here is my coding part. Hope will know the mistake that i made.

Designer code :

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        String personID = "";
        try
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connStr = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            connStr.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = healthlivin; Uid = root; Pwd = khei92;";
            String searchPerson = "SELECT PersonIDB from contactFriend WHERE PersonID = @id";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmdSearch = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(searchPerson, connStr);
            connStr.Open();
            cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "M000001");


            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader dtrRead2 = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader();

            if (dtrRead2.Read())
            {
                personID = (String)dtrRead2["PersonIDB"];
            }

            dtrRead2.Close();
            connStr.Close();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label lblID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblID");
            string s = lblID.Text;

            if (s == personID)
            {
                lblID.Visible = false;
                e.Item.FindControl("photoImage").Visible = false;
                e.Item.FindControl("lblName").Visible = false;
                e.Item.FindControl("deleter").Visible = false;
                e.Item.FindControl("lblEmail").Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblID.Visible = true;
                e.Item.FindControl("photoImage").Visible = true;
                e.Item.FindControl("lblName").Visible = true;
                e.Item.FindControl("deleter").Visible = true;
                e.Item.FindControl("lblEmail").Visible = true;
            }
        }

    }
  </script>

<asp:Repeater ID="friendRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound = "ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    </HeaderTemplate>


    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
       <td>
       <div style=" padding-left:180px;"> 
           <div id="leftHandPost" style="float:left; width:120px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px;">
              <div id="childLeft" style=" padding-left:5px;">
                 <div id="photo"  style=" border: thin solid black; width:100px;height:100px;">
                   <asp:Image id="photoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Concat("Images/", Eval("Picture")) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                 </div>
               </div><!--childLeft-->
            </div><!--leftHandPost-->
            </div>
        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div id="rightHandPost" style=" float:right; padding-right:260px;">
                                <div id="childRight" style="width:400px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px; padding-left:10px;">
                                    <strong><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonName") %></asp:Label></strong><br />
                                    <div style=" float:right; padding-right:10px;">

                                    <asp:ImageButton id="deleter" ImageUrl="App_Themes/Health/images/blue/Add.png" CausesValidation="False" runat="server"
                        AlternateText="Add" ImageAlign="absmiddle" BorderStyle="None" Width="21" Height="21"
                         OnCommand="add" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this?');" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PersonID") %>' />
                         </div><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonID") %></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server"><%# Eval("Email") %></asp:Label>
                                </div><!--childRight-->
                            </div><!--rightHandPost-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr>
       <td>
       <div style=" padding-left:180px;"> 
           <div id="Div1" style="float:left; width:120px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px;">
              <div id="Div2" style="padding-left:5px;">
                 <div id="Div3"  style=" border: thin solid black; width:100px;height:100px;">
                   <asp:Image id="photoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Concat("Images/", Eval("Picture")) %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                 </div>
               </div><!--childLeft-->
            </div><!--leftHandPost-->
        </div>
        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div id="Div4" style=" float:right; padding-right:260px;">
                                <div id="Div5" style="width:400px; height:120px; border: medium solid #cdaf95; padding-top:5px; padding-left:10px;">
                                    <strong><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonName")%></asp:Label></strong>
                                    <div style=" float:right; padding-right:10px;">
                                    <asp:ImageButton id="deleter" ImageUrl="App_Themes/Health/images/blue/Add.png" CausesValidation="False" runat="server"
                        AlternateText="Add" ImageAlign="absmiddle" BorderStyle="None" Width="21" Height="21"
                         OnCommand="add" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this?');" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PersonID") %>' />
                         </div><br />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server"><%# Eval("PersonID") %></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:Label id="lblEmail" runat="server"><%# Eval("Email") %></asp:Label>
                                </div><!--childRight-->
                            </div><!--rightHandPost-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

For the PageLoad :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connStr = new MySqlConnection();
                connStr.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = healthlivin; Uid = root; Pwd = khei92;";
                String searchOverall = "SELECT PersonID, PersonName, Email, Picture FROM Person";
                MySqlCommand cmdSearch = new MySqlCommand(searchOverall, connStr);
                connStr.Open();

                MySqlDataReader dtrRead2 = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader();
                friendRepeater.DataSource = dtrRead2;
                friendRepeater.DataBind();
                dtrRead2.Close();
                dtrRead2 = null;

                connStr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }            
        }             
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the MessageBox error handling and for the inline CSS

Comment: Erhmm~~ So sorry I not understand.. can explain further?

Answer (score 2):

Try making the entire item invisible instead of piece by piece, like this:

```
if (s == personID)
{
    e.Item.Visible = false;
}
```

Alternatively, you can filter the results by the condition before you bind to the repeater control.

Comment: I have try to make entire thing to invisible but there are not function. Which mean the entire ItemDataBound are not function? As you say before bind the repeater control filter the result can briefly explain on it? really very thank you :D

Comment: I assume you are doing some kind of search functionality? Whatever control (i.e. button) invokes the search, then in that click handler change your SQL SELECT to include the where clause for the value typed in the text box instead of trying to match the text box value when binding.

Comment: Hi, I had solve my problem. By the way, I just will hide the first row of database content. If i want to hide more than 1 what should I do? thank you

Comment: @user2769165 - if you feel this answer/discussion helped, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept this answer. :-)

Comment: @user2769165 - what did you change your query to make it work?

Comment: Oopss.. sorry.. My reputation are not enough to vote you. 
I change the query of
Label lblID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblID");
            string s = lblID.Text;

to 

String s = (String)(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "PersonID"));

but then this only retrieve 1 record. It only hide 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter data in your SQL query to bind only wanted data to the repeater.

I assume that you want to hide the rows which already added to **contactFriend** table by filling **PersonIDB** and **date** value, don't you?

If so, you should change the SQL query string to be such as

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.PersonName, p.Email, p.Picture 
 FROM Person AS p JOIN contactFriend AS cf ON p.PersonID = cf.PersonID 
 WHERE cf.PersonIDB IS NOT NULL AND cf.[date] IS NOT NULL
```

And this is other filtered query to use if you never have PersonID data in contactFriend table until you added the PersonIDB value (I mean you insert PersonID togather with PersonIDB to create new row at that time)

```
SELECT PersonID, PersonName, Email, Picture 
FROM Person 
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID FROM contactFriend)
```

Comment: Which mean I not need to use the ItemDataBound any more?

Comment: No, you still need to by data to repeater, but you could remove the check point out, I mean this scope **if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){ ... }**

Comment: BUt I already bind it in the pageload and it work. 

SELECT PersonID, PersonName, Email, Picture 
FROM Person 
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonIDB FROM contactFriend WHERE PersonID = @id)
I change this to my pageload and is work.

Comment: Oh now I see, if you have bind data in page load event, and you don't need to edit data while binding it to the repeater, then you are right, you don't need to handle the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: Haha... Thank you very much. That is work. And if I don't want to show the record of the owner which mean the logged in person what i should do?

Comment: First, store the username somewhere(such as Session or Cookies) when user logged in, then pass the stored username to your SQL query. For sample, if you have UserInfo table to store user log in information and this table link to Person table by key names PersonID, then you should change query to be like this "SELECT p.PersonID, p.PersonName, p.Email, p.Picture FROM Person p JOIN UserInfo u ON u.PersonID = p.PersonID WHERE p.PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonIDB FROM contactFriend WHERE PersonID = @id) AND u.username <> @username"